# Center image within div in HTML

Tags: html

I have a `div` and I would like to center the image inside the `div` **both horizontally and vertically**. I do not want to use `CSS page`. I want to learn how to do this using only `html` with CSS inline.

```
<div id="circle1" style="position:absolute;">
    <img id="circle1img" style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%"/>
</div>
```

I set the position of the `div` and the size of the image at run time in the following way:

```
var divW = randomInt(200,300);
var imgW = randomInt(20,120);
document.getElementById("circle1").width = divW;
document.getElementById("circle1").height = divW;
document.getElementById("circle1img).width = imgW;
document.getElementById("circle1img").height = imgW;
```

This does not currently work.

---

Here is a stand alone to test it out. Note that all the javascript customizations of the css are necessary and CANNOT be put inside the inline text. So please do not do this as a solution. Thanks!! You can see from this example that the border is around the image and not the `circle1` div.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="circles" style="display:none">
    <div id="circle1" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">
        <img id="circle1img"/>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/Javascript">

document.getElementById("circle1img").src = "37.png";
document.getElementById("circle1").style.left = "200px";
document.getElementById("circle1").style.top = "200px";
document.getElementById("circle1").style.border = "2px solid blue";

var divW = 200;
var imgW = 100;
document.getElementById("circle1").width = divW;
document.getElementById("circle1").height = divW;
document.getElementById("circle1img").width = imgW;
document.getElementById("circle1img").height = imgW;

document.getElementById("circles").style.display = "block";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ummmmmm, ur using css.... `style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%"` is just inline.....

Comment: That's what I meant, I want to do it inline

Comment: same crap... exact same css......

Comment: This code does not work...that's the point.

Comment: it doesnt work in regular css then.....

Comment: Yes exactly right...i want to get it working, and with inline css...lol

Answer (score 0):

From HTML perspective, it will be:

```
<div id="circle1" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">
    <img id="circle1img" src="your_image_src_goeshere..." />
</div>
```

Let me know if it resolves the issue or not.

**EDIT:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="circles" style="display:none">
    <div id="circle1" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">
        <img id="circle1img"/>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/Javascript">

document.getElementById("circle1img").src = "37.png";
document.getElementById("circle1").style.left = "200px";
document.getElementById("circle1").style.top = "200px";
document.getElementById("circle1").style.border = "2px solid blue";

var divW = 200;
var imgW = 100;
document.getElementById("circle1").width = divW;
document.getElementById("circle1").height = divW;
document.getElementById("circle1img").width = imgW;
document.getElementById("circle1img").height = imgW;
document.getElementById("circle1img").style.padding = 5;

document.getElementById("circles").style.display = "block";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But now, if I put a border around the circle1 div, for example, the border ends up only around the image, not the entire div

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Also...text-align only aligns it horizontally

Comment: Please see my edited code with addition of document.getElementById("circle1img").style.padding = 5;